# Android Studio re-build third-party jar file with 32bit

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have made an Android app, and I add the QQ tencent library SDk into it.
I put the sdk in the Android folder /libs open_sdk_r5043_lite.jar

the jar file contains

```
├─assets
|  |_____libwbsafeedit
|  |_____com.tencent.open.config.json
├─com
│  └─tencent
│      ├─connect
│      │  ├─a
│      │  ├─auth
│      │  ├─common
│      │  └─share
│      ├─open
│      │  ├─a
│      │  ├─b
│      │  ├─c
│      │  ├─utils
│      │  └─web
│      │      └─security
│      └─tauth
└─META-INF
```

and compile the library in build.gradle

```
compile files('libs/open_sdk_r5043_lite.jar')
```

and I start to build / run the app,
but when I ran the app, it shows error message.

```
    08-07 14:52:57.507  14959-14959/com.commandp.me E/Crittercism﹕ Unable to send crash
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.tencent.connect.auth.AuthDialog
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
        at crittercism.android.bc.c(Unknown Source)
        at crittercism.android.bc.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at crittercism.android.ar.a(Unknown Source)
        at crittercism.android.aq.uncaughtException(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
08-07 14:52:57.507  14959-14959/com.commandp.me E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.commandp.me, PID: 14959
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.commandp.me/files/libwbsafeedit.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
        at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:331)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:981)
        at com.tencent.connect.auth.AuthDialog.<clinit>(ProGuard:80)
        at com.tencent.connect.auth.AuthAgent$1$1.run(ProGuard:247)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

can anyone help me??
for rebuild 32bit in Android Studio??

Answer (score 0):

try the following in your build.gradle

```
    
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'assets/libwbsafeedit'
}
```